# How to write conditional for dataframe for first and last occurrences of conditions that are met?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
row  issue_status  market_phase       trade_type
 0        20           0                    
 1        10           0                    
 2        20           0                    
 3        10           0                    
 4        10           0                    
 5        10           0
```

I would like to map the first instance of (`issue_status == 10` & `market_phase == 0`) to `OPENING_AUCTION`.

And any subsequent occurrences of the above, I would like to map it to `CONTINUOUS_AUCTION`.

So I would like the dataframe to look like this:

```
row  issue_status  market_phase                   trade_type
 0        20           0              ->        
 1        10           0              ->       OPENING_AUCTION
 2        20           0              ->       
 3        10           0              ->       CONTINUOUS_TRADING
 4        10           0              ->       CONTINUOUS_TRADING
 5        10           0              ->       CONTINUOUS_TRADING
```

Here is my code:

```
market_info_df.loc[market_info_df['issue_status' == '10', 'market_phase' == '0'].iloc[0]] = MARKET_STATES.OPENING_AUCTION

market_info_df.loc[market_info_df['issue_status' == '10', 'market_phase' == '0']].iloc[1:] = MARKET_STATES.INTRADAY_AUCTION
```

When I run the above I get `KeyError: (False, False, False)`

Note that I need to use `iloc` in the code- any ideas how I would achieve the above?

Answer (score 0):

Disregarding performances, you can iterate through your dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'row': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                   'issue_status': [20, 10, 20, 10, 10, 10],
                   'market_phase': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                   'trade_type': None},)

trade_type_column = df.columns.get_loc("trade_type") # so you can use iloc

already_done = False
for row in range(len(df)):
    if df.loc[row, 'issue_status'] == 10 and df.loc[row, 'market_phase'] == 0:
        if not already_done:
            df.iloc[row, trade_type_column] = 'OPENING_AUCTION'
            already_done = True
        else:
            df.iloc[row, trade_type_column] = 'CONTINUOUS_TRADING'
```

This is what I get:[image: final_dataframe]

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the most efficient solution, but it's possible using [`df.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and [`np.argmax`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html#numpy.argmax).

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"row": [0,1,2,3,4,5],
                   "issue_status": [20,10,20,10,10,10],
                   "market_phase": [0,0,0,0,0,0],
                   "trade_type": [""] * 6})
# First set the trade_type column for all rows where the condition matches to `CONTINUOUS_TRADING`
df.loc[(df.issue_status.values == 10) & (df.market_phase.values == 0), 'trade_type'] = 'CONTINUOUS_TRADING'

# Set trade_type for first occurrence of condition to "OPENING_AUCTION"
df.loc[((df.issue_status.values == 10) & (df.market_phase.values == 0)).argmax(), 'trade_type'] = 'OPENING_AUCTION'

print(df)
```

Output:

```
   row  issue_status  market_phase          trade_type
0    0            20             0
1    1            10             0     OPENING_AUCTION
2    2            20             0
3    3            10             0  CONTINUOUS_TRADING
4    4            10             0  CONTINUOUS_TRADING
5    5            10             0  CONTINUOUS_TRADING
```

Answer (score 0):

Identify the rows where `issue_status` is `10` and `market_pahase` is `0` then identify the duplicate rows.. now using this information along with `loc` to fill the corresponding values in the `trade_type` column

```
cols = ['issue_status', 'market_phase']
m1 = df[cols].eq([10, 0]).all(1)
m2 = df[cols].duplicated()

df.loc[m1 & ~m2, 'trade_type'] = 'OPENING_AUCTION'
df.loc[m1 &  m2, 'trade_type'] = 'CONTINUOUS_TRADING'
```

Result

```
   row  issue_status  market_phase          trade_type
0    0            20             0                 NaN
1    1            10             0     OPENING_AUCTION
2    2            20             0                 NaN
3    3            10             0  CONTINUOUS_TRADING
4    4            10             0  CONTINUOUS_TRADING
5    5            10             0  CONTINUOUS_TRADING
```

Comment: Thanks Shubham, but I am working with a very big dataframe, and I'm trying to achieve the above 'on the fly' - any chance you can build on the code I have, as I believe that would map things on the fly rather than iterating through thr whole dataframe, as this will be quite expensive. Sorry I should have mentioned in my question it is a big dataframe.

Comment: @PatrickChong Glad to help. Here we are not iterating the solution is completely vectorized.